# Обработка несуществующих ссылок и страницы на сайте

Tags: php, apache, page

Есть некоторый ресурс, который я поднял на сервере *Apache*, есть допустим некоторое кол-во изображений на самой странице с возможностью переключать страницы переходя на *url* по типу `site/1, site/2` через навигатор. Вопрос в том, можно ли это сделать без создания директорий на самом сервере через обработку содержания адресной строки и делая выборку? Есть база данных, а там информация о том, на какой странице каждая картинка и размещении картинки на ресурсе высчитывается через общее кол-во на какой странице она будет. А может подобные директории просто создаются динамически?
И в дополнении к этому, я видел сайты, которые могли обрабатывать ссылки, которых точно нет: *site/2/1/4/5/3* ... и всё равно как-то обрабатывает не выдавая `Not Found`, но ведь через слеш указываются директории на сервере, а браузер просто берет оттуда `index.html` и не выводит в адресной строке, а там было совсем иначе и напрямую через `index.html/index.php` нельзя было перейти, даже идей нет как это сделано.

Comment: для начала стоит ознакомиться [вот с этим](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3_(%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82))

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался с htacces, вроде всё работает как нужно =)